# Use same random line from file in two functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, mitmproxy

I am trying to set a cookie if incoming requests url contains a keyword. (**This part is working**)

And based on how the website responds in it's "Location" header take further action, removing cookie line from the file in this case.
I have tried craming everything together under "def request(flow)" function, but that didn't work.

As you might have already guessed from the code I'm not a programmer, but spent two last nights putting this code together from snippets,
So, how do I delete the same cookie that was used in request based on the response?

*Thank you in advance!*
P.s The error I'm currently getting is -

"**lines.remove(v)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list**"

```
     import random
    from mitmproxy import ctx
    
v = random.choice(list(open('/etc/mitm/cookies.txt')))
cookie = v.strip()
    
    def request(flow):
        
   
        url = flow.request.pretty_url
        matches = ["needcookie", "nocookie"]
        if any(x in url for x in matches):
         flow.request.headers[b'Cookie'] = cookie
    
    def response(flow):
        if flow.response.headers.get("Location", "").startswith("https://www.mywebsite.com/nocookie?"):
            lines = []
            with open('/etc/mitm/cookies.txt') as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
            lines.remove(v)
            with open("/etc/mitm/deleted.txt", "w") as f:
                    f.write("%s\n" % v.strip())
            with open("/etc/mitm/cookies.txt", "w") as f:
                for line in lines:
                    f.write("%s\n" % line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Had to use global variables, working solution-**

```
import random
from mitmproxy import ctx



v = random.choice(list(open('/etc/mitm/cookies.txt')))
cookie = v.strip()

def request(flow):

    global v,cookie
    url = flow.request.pretty_url
    matches = ["needcookie", "cozzzzm"]
    if any(x in url for x in matches):
     ctx.log.warn("200")
     flow.request.headers[b'Cookie'] = cookie
   
def response(flow):
    global v,cookie
    if flow.response.headers.get("Location", "").startswith("https://www.mywebsite.com/nocookie"):
        lines = []
        with open('/etc/mitm/cookies.txt') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        lines.remove(v)
        with open("/etc/mitm/deleted.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write("%s\n" % v.strip())
        with open("/etc/mitm/cookies.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write("%s\n" % line.strip())
    v = random.choice(list(open('/etc/mitm/cookies.txt')))
    cookie = v.strip()
```